# flash[:notice] is not displaying when the user is logged out in Ruby on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.9.3. I want to show a flash[:notice] on form submission, but the problem is when the user is logged in then a flash message is shown perfectly, but when the user is not logged in and submit this form then the flash message is not shown.

**In controller/create action**

```
if @ticket
  flash[:notice] = "Thank you for contacting LittleCast. We have received your message and it has been routed to concerned department."
  redirect_to new_contact_request_path
else
  render :new
end
```

**In application.html.erb**

```
<% if flash[:notice].present? %>
  <div class="success-dv"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What gem/mechanism do you use for authentication?

Comment: Check maybe not logged user is redirected one more time after `redirect_to new_contact_request_path`. Other words: maybe not logged user submit form successfully, you redirect him to `new_contact_request_path` and you have one more redirection (for anonymous) there. If this is a reason then `flash.keep` should help you